# firebase Is it possible to update a transaction on disconnect()

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have to maintain maxCountOfConcurrent Users in a day.
For this I was thinking of adding a transaction,

currently i use something like this to remove the username from online users

```
rootScope.userPresenceRef.onDisconnect().remove();
```

Is it possible to have something like this

```
 rootScope.userPresenceRef.onDisconnect().transaction(function(count) {});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An `onDisconnect()` handler is implemented as a single write operation on the server, when it detects that the client has disconnected. At this point there is no way for the server to talk to the client anymore, so the write operation must consist purely of data that can be determined at the time the `onDisconnect()` handler is registered.

Since a transaction in Firebase requires communication between the client and the server, there is no way to run a transaction on disconnect. You will have to find a way to model the data without requiring it to be a transaction.

Answer (score 0):

You can use functions

1. Structure Your Data as

   usersData -> uid -> status - online/offline
2. Listen to update changes of status in functions
3. if change -> online (make transition to increase count else to decrease count)